# Radio Button selection Changes Toast on Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I was writing a simple test application. There are two radio buttons within the app. There id's are "radio_red" and "radio_blue". I wanted to create an onClickListener event that read the text associated to the button and then returned a basic "Right" or "Wrong" toast.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
        String ans =  rb.getText().toString();
        String an1 = "";

        if (ans.trim() == "Yes") {
            ans = "That's Right.";
        }
            else if (ans.trim() == "No") {
                ans = "thats wrong.";
            }
            else {
                ans = "none.";
            }

        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ans , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

So far no joy. Here is my code snippet. I've checked my "main.xml" and the text associated to the buttons are referneced correctly. I added trim to make sure of that. However, all that is ever returned in the toast is "none." What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to deal with the [`RadioGroup`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html), not the `RadioButton`.  The `RadioGroup` can tell you more meta-details about the radio controls, like which one is checked.  For example, in your listener you should use [`RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId()).

Alternatively, you could add a listener to the RadioGroup itself that sets a toggle in the background, using [`RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener)).  It has the capability of telling you which `RadioButton` was pressed.

Comment: Thanks Dan,

I ended up setting using .setOnCheckedChangeListener(). A apreciated the helpful links.
Bub

Comment: yes but.....https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4785
onCheckedChangeListener bug....

Answer (score 6):

I was getting same problem before....I have got the proper solution for it.

```
radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                Toast.makeText(Location.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have done one mistake in writing *Condition* here,

```
ans.trim() == "Yes"
```

It should be,

```
ans.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
package com.example.rediocheckbox;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup rad_grp;
    Button clear,submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        clear = findViewById(R.id.clear);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        rad_grp = findViewById(R.id.rad_grp);
        rad_grp.clearCheck();


        rad_grp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                RadioButton rb = group.findViewById(checkedId);
                if (null != rb && checkedId > -1)
                {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rad_grp.clearCheck();
            }
        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioButton rb = rad_grp.findViewById(rad_grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+rb.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rad_grp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other"/>


    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You could improve this answer a lot by [edit]ing and explaining it. Code dumps rarely make good answers, as people can't learn that much from them, and tend to copy & paste some code from the web. See [answer].