# Checked conditions of radio buttons are not working

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button

I have this code:

```
if(ratingRB.isChecked() == true)
{
    Toast.makeText(hotelSearch.this, "Please enter the rating as a word. (Ex. Five)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    if(showAllRB.isChecked() == true)
    {
       nearest.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

but when I check any of the 2 radio buttons(ratingRB, showAllRB) nothing happens.

`nearest`is a checkbox that is disabled from the beginning and I want when the user selects `showAllRB`, the checkbox is enabled.. what's wrong? and what should I do?

Comment: Side comment: you can replace `if(ratingRB.isChecked() == true)` by simply `if(ratingRB.isChecked())`.

Comment: The 2 expressions are strictly equivalent so it is unlikely to solve your issue hence "side comment"!

Comment: Can you include a bit more code than that - the event handler is absent from this which is making this more difficult to figure out? The SO users reading this are not mind-readers to your question.

Comment: @MahaK : You are showing your `if/else` out of context. Show more code to include where that block is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question: [Radio Button selection Changes Toast on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740169/radio-button-selection-changes-toast-on-android)

You want to add your `RadioButtons` to a `RadioGroup` and then implement a `RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working, what do you think is wrong?
    
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(buttonView.equals("Rating"))
  {
   Toast.makeText(hotelSearch.this, "Please enter the rating as a word. (Ex. Five)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else if((buttonView.getText().toString()).equals("Show All"))
  {
   nearest.setEnabled(true);
  }
  
 }